# TYPO3 & tx_news need ViewHelper for show count of Entities in category

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

Task: in category menu show count of item in each category, like

- Category_one (38)
- Category_two (14)
- Etc ...

I have try count by $demand but did'nt work

```
<?php
    namespace HIT\huskytheme\ViewHelpers\News;

    class CountCategoriesViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

        /**
         * @var \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository
         * @inject
         */
        protected $newsRepository = null;

        /**
         * 
         * @param string $category
         * @return string
         */
        public function render($category) {

            $demand = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('GeorgRinger\\News\\Domain\\Model\\Dto\\NewsDemand');
            //$demand->setDateField('datetime');

            $demand->setStoragePage(10, true);

            // for example by id = 2
            $demand->setCategories(2);

            $demand->setCategoryConjunction('and');
            $demand->setIncludeSubCategories('1');
            //$demand->setArchiveRestriction($settings['archiveRestriction']);

            $statistics = $this->newsRepository->countByCategories($demand);
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($statistics);

            return $this->newsRepository->countByCategories($demand); 

        }

    }
```

But get just 0, if call

```
{namespace s=HIT\huskytheme\ViewHelpers} 
{s:news.countCategories(category: 2)}
```

Comment: You can count news entity with userFun for particular category, why you don't use that method?

Comment: Cause - its old school approach. Will be better have regular ViewHelper for my Fluid templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualy i found way to get number of news in Category. Thx [Georg Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389552/georg-ringer) and [undko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540152/undko)

My ViewHelper

```
<?php

namespace HIT\huskytheme\ViewHelpers\News;

class CountCategoriesViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * @var \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $newsRepository = null;


    /**
     * 
     * @param \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($category) {
        /* @var $demand \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Dto\NewsDemand */
        $demand = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Dto\NewsDemand::class);

        $demand->setCategories(array($category));
        $demand->setCategoryConjunction('and');
        $demand->setIncludeSubCategories(false);

        return count($this->newsRepository->findDemanded($demand));
    }
}
```

And in my tx_news Templates/Category/List.html

```
<!-- load my ViewHelper -->
{namespace s=HIT\huskytheme\ViewHelpers}
```

and here add count

```
...
                            <f:link.page title="{category.item.title}" class="current-item" pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                                         additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}">{category.item.title}
                                <span class="postnum">({s:news.countCategories(category: category.item)})</span>
                            </f:link.page>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `countByCategories` which implements something like a demand object. Please just use a direct call to the DB.

Comment: It‘s important to mention that Oleg‘s code doesn‘t break (but return 0) because it‘s a valid magic method call, albeit useless.

Comment: About my question: why function "findDemanded" have "$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);" but "countDemanded" haven't and get StoragePid as "0". So i can get list my "findDemanded" corectly but can't do the same directly by "countDemanded"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of categories and the need to show this menu on uncached pages I‘d suggest to not go the view helper way but query DB (as Georg suggested) directly in the controller. Just connect a slot of yours to signal `GeorgRinger\News\Controller\CategoryController` : `listAction`. You‘ll get all categories there (in argument `categories`) and can launch a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_category_record_mm … GROUP BY uid_local
```

to fetch all counts in one go. Then simply add a new key to the array you return and use it in your template under that name.