# typoscript for a news category menu searched

Tags: typo3, tx-news

i'm searching for a news category menu with subcategories and number of relevant items.

There is on existing:
https://www.fiedomedia.de/news/artikel/news-kategorien-mit-counter/

This typoscript seems not to work in TYPO3 8.7.1

The number of items is wrong and the subcategories are repeated under every main category.

Has somebody a working script?

Comment: Try my ViewHelper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119101/typo3-tx-news-need-viewhelper-for-show-count-of-entities-in-category/44153942#44153942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the fluid-template for categories https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/Category/List.html
and use the count-viewhelper there
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/CountViewHelper.html

I did something like that some time ago with the dateMenu:

```
<f:section name="content">
    <ul class="vertical menu">
        <f:for each="{data.single}" key="year" as="months">
            <li>
                <a>{year}</a>
                <ul class="vertical menu nested">
                    <f:for each="{months}" key="month" as="count">
                        <f:if condition="{0:year, 1:month} == 
{0:overwriteDemand.year, 1:overwriteDemand.month}">
                            <f:then>
                                <li class="item active">
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <li class="item">
                            </f:else>
                        </f:if>
                            <f:link.action pageUid="{listPid}" arguments="
{overwriteDemand:{year: year, month: month}}"><f:translate key="month.
{month}" /> {year}
({count})</f:link.action>

                        </li>
                    </f:for>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:section>
```